# How to create a dropdown menu in QGIS Toolbar with Python

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qt

I Have a set of some QAction in my QGIS-Plugin and they are created and added to the toolbar like this

```
icon = QIcon(":/action1.png")
self.action1 = QAction(icon, u"Action 1", self.iface.mainWindow())
QObject.connect(self.action1, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.someMethod)
self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action1)
self.iface.addPluginToMenu(u"&My Plugin", self.action1)
```

But now I'd like to group my Actions like in this "Select Feature" Screenshot:
http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/6375/selectfeaturedropdown.png

Is this possible with Python in QGIS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### QToolButton

Starting from QGIS 2.0 there is `iface.addToolBarWidget` which lets you add a [QToolButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html) which allows fine grained control over dropdown behavior and appearance.

```
self.action1 = QAction(QIcon(":/action1.png"), u"Action 1", self.iface.mainWindow())
self.action2 = QAction(QIcon(":/action2.png"), u"Action 2", self.iface.mainWindow())
self.action3 = QAction(QIcon(":/action3.png"), u"Action 3", self.iface.mainWindow())

self.popupMenu = QMenu( self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.popupMenu.addAction( self.action1 )
self.popupMenu.addAction( self.action2 )
self.popupMenu.addAction( self.action3 )

self.action1.triggered.connect( self.someMethod1 )
self.action2.triggered.connect( self.someMethod2 )
self.action3.triggered.connect( self.someMethod3 )

self.toolButton = QToolButton()

self.toolButton.setMenu( self.popupMenu )
self.toolButton.setDefaultAction( self.action1 )
self.toolButton.setPopupMode( QToolButton.InstantPopup )

self.iface.addToolBarWidget( self.toolButton )
```

## QGIS <= 1.8

Up to QGIS 1.8, you could not do quite the same thing, because you could only add [QActions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html) to the QToolBar, but no [QToolButtons](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html) ( which would let you set the [PopupMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum) manually)

But you can get almost the same result if you assign a [QMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenu.html) to your action, and to this menu you can add other actions. I did not find a possibility to change the [PopupMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum) for this to anything else than MenuButtonPopup.

```
self.action1 = QAction(QIcon(":/action1.png"), u"Action 1", self.iface.mainWindow())
self.action2 = QAction(QIcon(":/action2.png"), u"Action 2", self.iface.mainWindow())
self.action3 = QAction(QIcon(":/action3.png"), u"Action 3", self.iface.mainWindow())

self.popupMenu = QMenu( self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.popupMenu.addAction( self.action2 )
self.popupMenu.addAction( self.action3 )

self.action1.triggered.connect( self.someMethod1 )
self.action2.triggered.connect( self.someMethod2 )
self.action3.triggered.connect( self.someMethod3 )

self.action1.setMenu( self.popupMenu )

self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action1)
```

Comment: hmm addToolBarIcon should really return a QAction so it saves having to make the action first.

Comment: I would really love to see an addToolBarButton method to allow finer grained control.

Comment: Well there is no API freeze yet ;)

Comment: Nathan W: addToolBarWidget() et.al. available now in master.